# Greatest lower bound for subordination

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Consider the set $X$ of all analytic functions $f$ in the unit disk $U$ satisfying
$f(0)=0, f'(0)\neq 0$. We say that $f\prec g$ if there exists
$\phi\in X$ which maps $U$ into itself, and $f=g\circ\phi.$

This is called subordination. There are hundreds of papers with "subordination" in the title, but I could not find the answer to the following question:

> Does the greatest lower bound with respect to $\prec$ exist for arbitrary pair of functions in $X$ ?

Precisely: Let $f,g$ be elements of $X$. Does there exist $h\in X$ such that
$h\prec f,\; h\prec g$, and for every $p$ such that $p\prec f,\; p\prec g$, we have
$p\prec h$?

I am especially interested in the subclass $X_0\subset X$ of locally univalent functions, $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in U.$

Remark. 
For univalent  (injective)   functions, the g.l.b, corresponds to the intersection
of the image domains. That's why I conjecture that g. l. b. must always exist.

EDIT. For meromorphic functions, the answer is negative. Let $f$ be a conformal map of the unit disk onto the disk $|z-1|<2\;$, $f(0)=0$ and $g$ be a conformal map onto the disk $\{ |z-1|>1/2 \}\cup\{\infty\},\;$ $g(0)=0$. As the intersection of the two images is a ring, there is evidently no g.l.b.
For holomorphic functions it remains open.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the greatest lower bound may not exist. The counterexample was constructed by Andrei Gabrielov,
using the example of Milnor
explained in the paper by Poenaru, Extension des immersions en codimension 1, Séminaire Bourbaki, 10 (1966-1968), Exp. No. 342. Milnor's example was brought
to my attention in a comment by Misha to my other question
[Uniqueness theorem for conformal mapping](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257397/uniqueness-theorem-for-conformal-maping)